# in laravel how to set pdf print page size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, dompdf

I am generating pdf file  using "laravel-dompdf" package.

I want to set custom paper size

```
( width 21.0 CM ) ( Length 29.7 CM)
```

**my code**

```
$center_detail = Center::where('center_code','=',Auth::user()->code)->first();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('Center.View_downlad', compact('view','center_detail'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set your paper size like this:

```
$customPaper = array(0,0,567.00,283.80);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('Center.View_downlad', compact('view','center_detail'))->setPaper(customPaper, 'landscape');
```